# Firebase.firestore vs admin.firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm learning GCP and in their Firestore, I'm confused with the difference of Admin.firestore & Firebase.firestore.

this is the code for admin:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
    databaseURL: "https://<firestoreprojectnameurl>"
const db = admin.firestore();
  });
```

while this is the code for the firestore

```
const { config } = require('./config');
const firebase = require("firebase");
firebase.initializeApp(config);
const db = firebase.firestore();
```

Please note that only 1 db at a time will work and for my current set-up I use the `db = firebase.firestore()` although if I change it to `db = admin.firestore` ite works fine and all my code works the same.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The JavaScript SDK for web clients (your second example) is different than the JavaScript SDK for nodejs backends (your first example).  They have different APIs, though they might appear very similar for most types of queries.  But they are definitely not interchangeable.  You are supposed to pick the one that matches the environment where it's going to be used.  The Firebase Admin SDK is definitely not usable in web clients, though the web client SDK might work in nodejs backend environments (but I don't recommend it).

It might also help to know that the Firebase Admin SDK is actually just a wrapper around the Google Cloud nodejs SDK.  You can compare the API documentation of the [web SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore) to the [nodejs SDK](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/index.html) if you want to take a closer look.

Comment: If I understand your answer correctly, and please correct me if I an wrong, I should use the second code if I were to deploy the code in the google functions that will get triggered on behalf of the end users?

Comment: You would definitely want to use the Admin SDK for Cloud Functions.  That's what you see in all the official samples.

Comment: Thank you! and use the second code for client side scripts? right?

Comment: For running in a browser, yes, that's why my answer is saying.