# NextJs and Firestore initialization

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, firebase-admin

I am trying to use firebase in my NextJs project.

I created this

`initFirebase.tsx` for the server

```
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/nextjs';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

const initFirebaseAdmin = async (config: admin.AppOptions) => {
  try {
    if (!admin.apps.length) {
      admin.initializeApp({ ...config });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    Sentry.captureException(e);
  }
};

export const init = () => {
  initFirebaseAdmin({
    credential: admin.credential.cert({
      projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
      clientEmail: process.env.NEXT_FIREBASE_ADMIN_PRIVATE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
      privateKey: process.env.NEXT_FIREBASE_ADMIN_PRIVATE_KEY.replace(
        /\\n/g,
        '\n'
      ),
    }),
  });
};
```

and in my API I am doing

```
import { addDoc, collection, getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';

import { init } from '../initFirebase';

export async function createPlace(req: Request) {
  init();
  try {
    const payload: Place = await req.json();

    const response = await addDoc(collection(getFirestore(), 'test'), payload);

    return Response.json(response, {
      status: 201,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return Response.json({ error: 'internal_error' }, { status: 500 });
  }
}
```

Now, in most tutorial, this is enough, but somehow, I get

> FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call initializeApp() first (app/no-app).

The `admin.initializeApp({ ...config });` is correctly called without error.

Do I need to initialize firebase-admin AND firebase ? cause it doesnt look like It should be needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake you're making is mixing use of Firebase Admin SDK for backend servers and the Firebase client SDKs for web frontends.  They are completely different things and aren't interchangeable at all.  The latest versions of each don't even have similar APIs anymore.

If you're writing backend code with firebase-admin, you'll need to remove the firebase/firestore (and other firebase/* for the web client) dependencies entirely - they will not be useful.  Then, you can use firebase-admin alone to read and write Firestore according to what you see in the [API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.firestore).  firebase-admin is just a thin wrapper on top of the [@google-cloud/firestore nodejs package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/firestore), and has the same API.  Note that you will not be using functions like `doc()` and `addDoc()` that you see in the web client SDK.

See also:

- [Where is the Firebase Admin SDK docs for interacting with Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74132596/where-is-the-firebase-admin-sdk-docs-for-interacting-with-firestore)
- [Firebase.firestore vs admin.firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63664040/firebase-firestore-vs-admin-firestore)

Comment: Thank ! Yeah I actually found out while you were writing the response and update part of my code and it does work. I guess I got mixed up due to the fact that almost everything online use firebase client only and I rarely see any exemple and doc for admin so I thought it would be the same thing. And It looks way harder to manipulate the firebase admin compared to the client. Thank for clearing that up